# Is it way to wait some text via attribute

Tags: karate

I would like to wait some text in the following format:

```
waitUntil(locator, attribute, attributeValue)
```

Examples from tutorial page do not meet the necessary conditions:

```
And waitUntil('#eg01WaitId', "_.innerHTML == 'APPEARED!'")
And waitForText('#eg01WaitId', 'APPEARED')
```

Answer (score 0):

Take some time to read and understand the documentation. What you are looking for is this:

```
* waitUntil('.some-class', "_.getAttribute('some-attribute') == 'some-value'")
```